# Write log by Golang logger

Tags: go, logging

I am trying to write log by using `log.Logger`, my code is like bellow. I don't understand why my log can be written using Error inside `initLog` function but in `main` function it can't be written to the log file.
Can anybody explain for me?
Thanks.

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

const (
    PORT = ":8081"
)

var (
    Error *log.Logger
)

func initLog() {
    errorFile, err := os.OpenFile("error.log", os.O_RDWR|os.O_APPEND, 0660)
    defer errorFile.Close()

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    Error = log.New(errorFile, "ERROR: ", log.Ldate|log.Ltime)
    Error.SetOutput(errorFile)
    Error.Println("Log error will be written into error.log")

}

func main() {
    initLog()
    Error.Println("Test write log")
    http.ListenAndServe(PORT, http.FileServer(http.Dir('.')))
}
```

Comment: "in main function it can't" meaning what? What happens?

Comment: Sorry, I mean that when I call Error.Println in initLog function it work. However when I call Error.Println in main function it doesn't work.

Comment: Right. Please specify what "doesn't work" means. Won't compile, crashes, generates an error, doesn't print anything, prints the wrong thing... there are a million things "doesn't work" could mean here.

Comment: yep, I got it. In this context I mean it doesn't write any thing to the log file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're closing the file when returning from `initLog()`   using `defer errorFile.Close()` so inside `main()` the file `errorFile` is closed.

So comment this line:

```
defer errorFile.Close()
```

And move it to the `main()`.

Comment: I am learning golang, and I am researching about how to write log in golang. I felt that it is not easy like in java.

Comment: It's easy enough, Google it and you'll find many examples, see:  [1](https://blog.scalyr.com/2018/06/go-logging/), [2](https://logmatic.io/blog/our-guide-to-a-golang-logs-world/), [3](https://dave.cheney.net/2015/11/05/lets-talk-about-logging).

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `defer errorFile.Close()` in `initLog()`. As soon as `initLog()` returns the defer is executed and because of this, when `Error.Println("Test write log")` is called in your main, the io.Writer is already closed.

Also you should check for errors first and then call `defer <what ever you need to do>` like

```
errorFile, err := os.OpenFile("error.log", os.O_RDWR|os.O_APPEND, 0660)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer errorFile.Close()
```